# JavaScript - display number as non standard index?

Tags: javascript

In my JS, I've got a generated number (fairly enormous, it's normally about 95^[5-10]).
How do I stop this number from being displayed as standard notation?

Comment: How do you *want* it to be displayed?

Comment: In non standard index, e.g. I want `5.6,880,009,227,646e+21` to be displayed as `5,748,
511,570,879,116,626,495`

Answer (score 2):

You can't. JavaScript cannot handle such large numbers natively, and the scientific notation helps emphasize that fact.

That said, you might be able to do some string manipulation on it, to strip out the `.` and process the exponent to find out how many zeroes to add to the end. Obviously it won't be accurate but that's because of the inability to handle such large numbers I mentioned.

Comment: Is it possible to do what I'm asking through PHP?